# Execute PHP function from a PHP string

Tags: php

I searched on google and on stackoverflow for this but i couldn't find any results.
What i want is to know if you can execute a php function from a string.
Why ? 
I have a function that creates a table after an array.
Thing is i want to, for example format a unix timestamp into a date but dynamically.
Example

```
 'Register date' => array(
      "<?php date('h:m:i',{RegDate}); ?>"
  ),
```

Is it possible ?
(I already have a function that converts {RegDate} to the respective row,so the only thing i need is to somehow execute the function date,if possible)

I tried eval and even just a simple echo,but every time htmls comments my php tags and they become

```
 <!--?php date('h:m:i',1362159376); ?-->
```

Comment: evaluating strings as code is usually a sign of poor design. Take a long hard look at your code and see if there is a better way to do what you want to do. If you do need to use eval, you pass it just the PHP code, without the <?php and ?> surrounding it.

Comment: I tried without the php tags but it just echos the plain string..

Comment: What does "`every time htmls comments my php tags`" mean? Did you verify that something converted your tags, or did you just look at the *view source* window output which is commonly adapted by browsers? -- You may wish to elaborate on application flow ("`table after an array`") and why you think that is necessary. Show your `eval` workaround attempt. Explain why you can't extend your placeholder syntax to support basic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anonymous functions for it:

```
'Register date' => function($regdate) {
    return date('h:m:i', $regdate);
},
```

Then call it like so:

```
call_user_func($x['Register date'], $row['date']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
'Register date' => array(
    date('h:m:i', RegDate))
```

From what I can see there's no reason to try and use variable parsing on this since date() returns a string already. If you really need to you can use the following:

```
'Register date' => array(
    "{date('h:m:i', RegDate)}")
```

The entire expression needs to be inside the {}'s of the string to execute, which is why in your example you were getting the timestamp but not the rest of the expression.

Comment: Well if i use the first thing that you suggested it is going to get executed from the array..and also i need to replace the regdate variable with a timestamp..so that wouldn't work.Second example,i have a preg match that takes what is in {} and puts it as an index for the variable $row which is the row from database..Thanks for the response tho.

Comment: Honestly it seems like you are trying to take a poor approach to the problem you are aiming to solve, it basically looks to me like you are trying to pass around code as parameters since you are wanting to store it in a string. You might be better served using anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

> What i want is to know if you can execute a php function from a string.

Yes you can, but it seems that this is not your question. Executing a function "from string":

```
<?php
    call_user_func('date', 'h:m:i', RegDate);
```

So if "dynamically" means you want to tell the function name as well, then this is the way.

You can also pass parameters as an array:

```
<?php
    call_user_func_array('date', array('h:m:i', RegDate));
```